# C++ : Make multiple constructors with the same argument types

Tags: c++, types, constructor, typedef, disambiguation

I would like to make a class with several constructors of the same type. As this is not directly possible, is there a simple way to define readable "dummy" types such as the class could look like:

```
class Myclass
{
    MyClass(Orange, std::string & name, float size);
    MyClass(Apple, std::string & name, float size);
    MyClass(Banana, std::string & name, float size);
}
```

I could define Orange, Apple and Banana as struct typedefs, but is there a more convenient way?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me `MyClass` is a base class, and you want three subclasses.

Comment: Would a factory class be more appropriate?  `MyClass.CreateBanana("Bananco", 10f);`

Comment: @jxh : this is exactly what I'm trying to get rid of. With a large number of small subclasses (>30) this is a mess, it's not copyable & passable by value without a shared pointer/clone wrapper class mechanism, requires dynamic casting, etc... and in my particular case it will be much simpler like that.

Comment: @ matthew : Yes, I considered it. But it lacks the possibilities of initializer lists and hence const members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library does this in various places actually, for example [std::piecewise_construct_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct_t). Their standard is to provide...

```
struct something_t {};

constexpr something_t something = something_t();
```

Comment: did you forget the typedefs?

Comment: I did not think it was possible to define an empty struct. Do I pass it by value or by pointer/reference? If by value, can the compiler completely optimize it out so that it's just here for strong typing at compile-time?

Comment: Hmm OK I was still thinking about C struct typedef requirement

Comment: @galinette By value, and yes it will be completely compiled out. And you can certainly define an empty struct. The purpose of `something` is so the user can pass that global into your constructor: `MyClass c(something, "name", 12.3f);` They actually don't really need to know about `something_t`

Comment: geeez I'm becoming a c++ guru (just kidding)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can tag dispatch to overload the constructor arbitrarily:

```
struct Orange{};
struct Apple{};
struct Banana{};

class MyClass
{
    MyClass(Orange, std::string & name, float size){}
    MyClass(Apple, std::string & name, float size){}
    MyClass(Banana, std::string & name, float size){}
};

int main()
{
    std::string name("Fred");   
    MyClass myObject(Orange(), name, 10.0f);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using a template parameter?

```
struct Orange {};
class MyClass
{
public:
    template<typename CT>
    MyClass(CT, std::string & name, float size);
};

template<>
MyClass::MyClass<Orange>(Orange, std::string & name, float size)
{
    // The orange case
}
```

Which could be used as:

```
int main()
{
    std::string name("Fred");
    MyClass myObject(Orange(), name, 12.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above form it is just a more complex route to the tag dispatch approach.
The advantage comes in that you can add extra details into template parameter and make a generic constructor based on them:

```
struct Orange { static const int pips = 7; };
struct Banana { static const int pips = 1; };

class MyClass
{
    int pips;
public:
    enum ConstructorType {Orange, Apple, Banana};
    template<typename CT>
    MyClass(CT, std::string & name, float size);
};

template<typename CT>
MyClass::MyClass(CT, std::string & name, float size)
: pips(CT::pips)
{

}
```

Comment: I did not know it was possible to template a constructor without templating the class, that's interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Named constructor idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-ctor-idiom.html). Basically, you create static methods with different names which return new objects.

Comment: I know this one, the issue is you can't use initializer lists as in a constructor. This means, no const members, double initializations, etc... not ideal